# How to solve the Error: "FirebaseInstanceId: Google Play services missing or without correct permission."?

Tags: kotlin, google-play-services, firebase-analytics

I catch this problem after add Firebase analytics to my Kotlin project, but my application working fluently. Although searching solution from Google but seems like its does not have solution to solve this. I want to know why this error appears and how to solve this, I'm afraid that it will affect to my  application performance in the future. Thanks a lot!!!

I use firebase-core: 16.0.7

my user-permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: I have the same issue. I have Google Play services installed and i've configured my project with Firebase dozens of times. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please, check that you have google play services installed.